# Is there a size limit for a .zip file using CopyHere in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, unzip

I have a vbscript that extracts multiple zip files to different locations. The code works for all but one file. This one file, that doesn't work, happens to be bigger than 6GB. The next, biggest, file that I am processing is around 3.5GB.

Here's a snippet of the code;

```
strFileDest = "path\to\some\dir1"
strZIPname = "file1.zip" 
Call UnPack(strFileDest, strZIPname)

strFileDest = "path\to\some\dir2"
strZIPname = "file2.zip" 
Call UnPack(strFileDest, strZIPname)

Function UnPack(strZIPdest, strZIPname)
  Dim intOptions, objShell, objSource, objTarget

  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  sSourceFile = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(strZIPname)
  Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(sSourceFile).Items()
  Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(strZIPdest)

 intOptions = 256
 If objFSO.FolderExists(strZIPdest) Then
   objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptions
 Else
   MsgBox "Cannot complete unzip for " & strZIPname & ". The destination _
   directory (" & strZIPdest & ") could not be located.", 0, "Invalid"
 End If
End Function
```

I have taken a smaller zip and renamed it as the zip that won't copy. With the new size, the script will unzip that file proving that the rest of the script for that file works. I have also verified that the zip is valid by manually extracting it. When I run the script with it pointing at the large zip, I receive no errors either (I'm not using *On Error resume next*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is. As far as I know it's around 2GB, though it's undocumented I've encountered it before. If you need to compress something larger than that, use the command line version of 7zip.

[Here is a VBScript wrapper I wrote for 7zip.](http://www.naterice.com/articles/38)

Comment: Thanks for the link; I actually landed on your page while researching a method to unzip. While the client that I am using does have 7zip already installed, I was reticent to use it in favor of using a native method. I may go down that road though.

Answer (score 0):

From windows Vista, zip64 is supported for reading. But creation of compressed folders seems to be limited to classic zip format. 4GB max file size, 65535 entries in zip file. And microsoft has documented problems in windows xp for compressed folders larger than 2GB.

Comment: So, there is a limit on reading...what about extracting? If I right-click and 'Extract All...' it works. Is that not the same engine that VB CopyHere is using?