# How can I be sure that a very large zip file is finished compressing?

Tags: windows, vbscript, zip, compression, large-files

I am writing a VBScript to try to compress multiple directories in different locations into the same Zip file.

The current solution I am using is to iterate over the directories I want to compress (of which there are currently 2), get the file objects and use the copyHere method to copy the source folder into a zip file with the proper header format.

That part seems to be working okay, the difficulty I am having is with the error checking. The only two solutions I have found online are to get the count of objects in the source and target directories and sleep until they are the same, or to check if the zip file is open for appending and sleep until it is.

The first option is easy with one directory but becomes much more tedious with multiple folders, not to mention that Windows will likely create an object in the target directory before it has finished copying and I am compressing files potentially over 10 GB so that solution won't work.

I had tried to implement the second solution but every time the loop got to the second call to CopyHere it would tell me that the zip file was corrupted from the first iteration. Is it not possible to compress very large files to a zip with VBScript?

Any other suggestions as to how I can error check that the compressing is done using VBScript would be very helpful.

Comment: There are problems documented with zip sizes above 2GB/4GB at least  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20009033/is-there-a-size-limit-for-a-zip-file-using-copyhere-in-vbscript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37411326/limiting-zip-file-size)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `Function Create_WinRar_Archive(Source,Target_Archive,Password)` to compress a folder with **rar.exe** command line of Winrar.
We can call this function by two ways :

If you want create an archive without password, so we called it by this way :

`Call Create_WinRar_Archive(Source,Target_Archive,"")`

or if you want to set to this archive a password just we called it as :

`Call Create_WinRar_Archive(Source,Target_Archive,Password)`

And here is an example to compress the **Pictures folder**

```
Option Explicit
Dim ws,Source,Target_Archive,Password
Set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Source = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%userprofile%\pictures")
Target_Archive = "C:\BackupImages.rar"
Password = "123456"
Call Create_WinRar_Archive(Source,Target_Archive,Password)
Wscript.echo "All files are archived successfully !"
ws.run "Explorer " & Target_Archive
'******************************************************************************************************
Function Create_WinRar_Archive(Source,Target_Archive,Password)
'This function executes the command line
'version of WinRAR and reports whether
'the archive exists after WinRar exits.
'If it exists then it returns true. If
'not it returns an error message.
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim oFSO,oShell,aScriptFilename,sScriptFilename
    Dim sWorkingDirectory,ProgramFiles,sWinRarLocation
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
'--------Find Working Directory--------
    aScriptFilename = Split(Wscript.ScriptFullName, "\")
    sScriptFilename = aScriptFileName(Ubound(aScriptFilename))
    sWorkingDirectory = Replace(Wscript.ScriptFullName, sScriptFilename, "")
'-------Ensure we can find Winrar.exe------
 If oFSO.FileExists(sWorkingDirectory & " " & "Winrar.EXE") Then
    sWinRarLocation = ""
    ElseIf oFSO.FileExists(oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ProgramFiles%\Winrar\rar.exe")) Then
        sWinRarLocation = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%programfiles%\Winrar\")
    ElseIf oFSO.FileExists(oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Winrar\rar.exe")) Then
        sWinRarLocation = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%programfiles(x86)%\Winrar\")
  Else
    Create_WinRar_Archive = "Error: Couldn't find Winrar.EXE"
    Exit Function
  End If
  '--------------------------------------
'The Command "A" Means ==> add to archive
'To create a WinRar file with the specified name after command A (archive) and the switches -ep1 (exclude base directory from names) and -r (recursive)
    If Password = "" Then
        oShell.Run """" & sWinRarLocation & "rar.exe"" A -ep1 -r """ & _
        Target_Archive & """ """ & Source & """",0,True
    Else
'The -hp<password> switch: To use a password
        oShell.Run """" & sWinRarLocation & "rar.exe"" A -ep1 -r -hp"&Password&" """ & _
        Target_Archive & """ """ & Source & """",0,True
    End If
    If oFSO.FileExists(Target_Archive) Then
        Create_WinRar_Archive = 1
    Else
        Create_WinRar_Archive = "Error: Creating archives failed !"
        MsgBox Create_WinRar_Archive,16,Create_WinRar_Archive
    End If
End Function
'****************************************************************************************************
```